# sql select items separated with ','

Tags: mysql, sql

I have colums:

```
name ids
tom   1
jeg   2
kom   2,7
eyr   4,8
mok   4,12
```

I have sql query:

```
select name from table where ids like %2%
```

I need get result: 
jeg 
kom

but get:
jeg
kom
mok

so how to edit this query? I understand why I get mok because like is %2%

Comment: With a better datamodel, you'd have a record relating one name to one id and could simply ask for `id = 2`.

Comment: Is it a legacy model?

Comment: No. Don't use FIND_IN_SET. Instead, fix your broken data model.

Answer (score 3):

Use `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(2, ids) > 0
```